# Passing viewmodel from one method to another (post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a wizardtype form where i would like to keep the model from the first step to the last.

This is how im doing it now, but i cant seem to keep the model from step 3 to 4.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(MemberViewModel model)
{
    var mobile = model.Mobile;
    var xml = MemberclubHelper.CreateVerificationTokenXML(mobile, "47");
    MemberclubHelper.SendVerificationToken(xml);
    return RedirectToAction("RegisterStep1", new { mobile = mobile });
}

public ActionResult RegisterStep1(string mobile)
{
    var model = new MemberViewModel();
    model.Mobile = mobile;
    return View("Register/Step1", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStep1(MemberViewModel model)
{
    var interests = (from interest in model.Interests where interest.isChecked select interest.value).ToList();
    var passing = (from pass in model.Passing where pass.isChecked select pass.value).ToList();

    var xml = MemberclubHelper.CreateMemberProfileXML(model.Mobile, model.FirstName, model.FirstName,
        model.Email1, model.Zipcode, model.SelectedKid1, model.SelectedKid2, model.SelectedKid3,
        model.Gender.ToString(), interests, passing);
    model.XmlToSend = xml;
    if (xml.Contains("error"))
    {
        model.ErrorMessage = xml;
        return View("Register/Step1", model);
    }

    return View("Register/Step2", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStep2(MemberViewModel model)
{
    var result = MemberclubHelper.SendCreateUser(model.XmlToSend, model.Password);
    if (result.Contains("error"))
    {
        model.ErrorMessage = result;
        return View("Register/Step2", model);
    }

    else
    {
        return View("Register/Finished");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be better served by creating a separate view model for each step (i.e.,  MemberViewModelStep1). To me this seems like only some of your MemberViewModel properties will will be set in each step unless you carry a lot of that state between steps via hidden inputs or some other mechanism.

Alternatively,  have you considered using JavaScript to build up that state between across your steps and then submitting a single post with your fully populated MemberViewModel?